# Stack Overflow Instant Search

Tags: app, javascript, search

**Screenshot**

[image: Instant search for Stack Overflow]

**About**

I love the concept of instant search that Google introduced. [Stack Overflow Instant Search](http://so-instant.appspot.com) does exactly that - it brings (almost) instant search to Stack Overflow. The results update as the user types. There's a 250ms delay before actually hitting the Stack Overflow servers, which I think is fine. I'd highly recommend you to log in before you search, because API calls are rate limited. So if you log in, the access token is sent along with the request so that the number of searches allowed to you is more. If something doesn't work as intended, or you have any questions/comments/protests/rants, please let me know! I'd love some feedback!

**License**

[BSD 3-Clause](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)

**Download**

There's no download. It's a web app - http://so-instant.appspot.com

**Platform**

Standalone web application

**Contact**

[Siddhant Goel](http://about.me/siddhantgoel)

**Code**

GitHub - https://github.com/siddhantgoel/so-instant

Comment: Looks promising.  It should display the number of posts found and the number displayed, though.

Comment: Looks good! I'm not sure how the search is supposed to work but I find if I type 2 or more words I often get zero results.  I take it that it is doing an `AND` condition thus if I type too many unrelated words (e.g. natural search) I won't get any matches. oh, and it is exact word matches.. so "xmlht" won't match on "XMLHTTPRequest" until I type the whole word. ;-)

Comment: Yeah that's a problem I noticed as well. The thing is that right now I send the query as is to the Stack Overflow servers. If I replace the spaces with OR or %20, in most cases I don't get anything back. I was looking through the API docs again but couldn't find something that'll enable substring matches either. If I don't find anything, then I can look into doing something with the database dumps they provide, although that's a last resort! But thanks for the feedback! I'll look through these issues in the next couple of days. :)

Comment: A search for `[php] [json]` returns lots of results without both tags: http://i.imgur.com/z6vrdxK.png

Comment: The link is broken. http://instant-overflow.appspot.com/